# How do I view the User Agent of outgoing requests to SharePoint made from my Azure Web Application?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-application-insights, sharepoint-online

I'm following the guidance from Microsoft on [decorating traffic to avoid throttling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online#how-to-decorate-your-http-traffic-to-avoid-throttling). This guidance specifies that you set a specific User Agent on outgoing requests from the application to SharePoint via CSOM when making API calls.

I have made this change, and would like to now verify that the User Agent is in fact appropriately modified on API calls to SharePoint.

My provider-hosted application is hosted on Azure, and while I can see CSOM calls to SharePoint (https://(mytenancy).sharepoint.com/sites/(mysite)/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery) in the Application Map as a dependency, I can't figure out how to view the actual outbound request so as to examine it for the User Agent string.

**How can I view the User Agent string on outbound requests from my Azure application?** How can I verify that I've set the User Agent string on my calls to the SharePoint API?

*Additional Info:*
I have tried running the application as well on localhost and employed the use of Wireshark and Fiddler, but I'm only picking up requests to client.svc/ProcessQuery with my browser's User Agent string. I get the feeling I'm not even seeing all the CSOM requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Agent is used for determining browser and browser version , however it seems to be dropped in processing and not available in search or export.

Please have a look  at below links for further details.

[UserAgent not transfered](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/558)

[UserAgent, Lat/Long and URL expansion data removed](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Announcements/issues/3)

Hope this information helps.

To provide feedback for the team on this specific feature , please refer to this [link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/36747712-let-us-capture-useragent-and-other-request-headers) and upvote.

Support for viewing Raw body requests is something being considered by the Product team. Please refer [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/13949925-add-support-for-viewing-raw-body-requests) for more details on it.